# Как не указывать порт при подключении к sql server через mssql в nodejs?

Tags: node.js, sql-server

```
await sql.connect(
    `Server=xxx.xx.x.xxx\\instance_name;Database=database;User Id=user_id;Password=password;Encrypt=true`,
)
```

При использовании варианта выше выдает ошибку:

```
ConnectionError: Failed to connect to xxx.xx.x.xxx:undefined - self signed certificate
```

Если после `Server` через запятую указать порт:

```
Server=xxx.xx.x.xxx\\instance_name, 1433;
```

То выдает ошибку:

```
ConnectionError: Port for instance_name, 1433 not found in xxx.xx.x.xxx
```

Очевидно, что порт не подходит

Раньше подключался через `tedious` и там порт не указывался, все работало отлично

Как не указывать порт при подключении через mssql?

Comment: попробуйте добавить `TrustServerCertificate=False`, cм. https://stackoverflow.com/a/38916324/4496422

Comment: Все равно тоже самое

Answer (score 0):

Проблему удалось решить следующим образом:

```
import sql from 'mssql';

const sqlConfig = {
    user: 'user', // Update me
    password: 'pass', // Update me
    server: 'xxx.xx.x.xxx\\INSTANCE', // Update me
    database: 'Database', // Update me
    trustServerCertificate: true,
    options: {
        encrypt: true,
    },
};

sql.connect(sqlConfig);
```